# Calculating (summing) error inside a for loop - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am comparing two functions, one is an analytical solution (straight out of a textbook), and the other is using experimental data I collected.

I need to compute the error between the two.  Here is my approach:

```
 voltage_experimental_offset = xlsread('R21_C19_L21.xlsx','H118:H259'); 
trigger_experimental = xlsread('R21_C19_L21.xlsx','D118:D259'); 
t_experimental = xlsread('R21_C19_L21.xlsx','G118:G259'); 

ii = length(voltage_experimental_offset);   
total = 0;

for i = 1:ii
error = (voltage_experimental_offset(i) - V_C(i)').^2;  % compute error
total = sum(error(:))                                   % sum error

end
```

The problem is that the 'total' just displays the 'error' every time.  **I want to add the error for each iteration**

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to index error

```
error = zeros(size(voltage_experimental_offset));
for i = 1:ii
error(i) = (voltage_experimental_offset(i) - V_C(i)').^2;  % compute error
total = sum(error(:))                                   % sum error

end
```

Comment: @user1412994: don't thank the answerer, upvote the answer and accept it.